# Calling a gnuplot script with arguments on windows is not working

Tags: windows, gnuplot, call

I tried passing variables to a gnuplot script as explained [here](http://theochem.ki.ku.dk/on_line_docs/gnuplot/gnuplot_18.html), but I only get an error message:

```
Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected
```

I am using gnuplot on Windows 7.
I had a friend try the same thing on Linux Mint and it works like a charm there.

Is this functionality just not included in the windows version of gnuplot or can I change something to accomplish the same thing? Is there another way to do this?

---

My script:

```
print "p0=$0 p1=$1 p2=$2 p3=$3 p4=$4 p5=$5 p6=$6 p7=x$7x"
```

How i call it:

```
gnuplot> call 'calltest.gp' "abcd" 1.2 + "'quoted'" -- "$2"
```

I use gnuplot Version 5.0 patchlevel 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to `call` must be strings. While conversion of numbers to strings works on Linux, it makes problems on Windows:

Wrong:

```
call 'script.gp' 'string' 12
```

Correct:

```
call 'script.gp' 'string' '12'
```

You must also note, that the `call` behavior was changed with version 5. Now, `ARG0` contains the naming of the called script, and the parameters are contained in variables `ARG1`, `ARG2` etc.

Comment: Well, this does eliminate the error message. However, the substitution of $0 etc. still doesn't work (I just get the unsubstituted string).

Comment: That was just a guess, since you don't provide any code showing what you are actually doing! And the gnuplot version you are using is also interesting (in gnuplot 5 several things changed). The documentation you linked is btw quite outdated, it refers to 3.7, whereas the current version is 5

Comment: Ah, that's it! I am using version 5.0 but didn't know about the new style substitution (ARG0, etc.). Mind making this a separate answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I edited the answer, since the first part refers to the error message you posted. The other thing with the different style of `call` in gnuplot 5 is, at first sight completely unrelated to your actual problem, since you don't show any code... Even if your problem is solved now, could you please include a code snippet of how you called the script and how you used the call parameters? Otherwise your question is quite useless for anyone else than you and should be closed.